# Preventing host discovery in network

Tags: network, defense

With tools such as Fing (Android app) and netdiscover (Kali Linux tool) its possible to get all connected devices in network.

How it's possible to prevent host discovery in a network?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple approaches an attacker can use for host discovery. I believe `netdiscover` uses ARP requests for host discovery, which operates on the Ethernet protocol (see https://github.com/alexxy/netdiscover). Other tools like `nmap` operate at higher protocol layers (ICMP, TCP/IP, UDP/IP, see https://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html). A solution which prevents host discovery at higher protocol layers may not prevent host discovery at lower layers, and vice versa.

A firewall is a common solution for preventing host discovery. For example, Linux can use `iptables` to prevent host discovery at higher layers and `arptables` at the lower layers. This doesn't protect against sniffing of traffic by a passive attacker (`netdiscover` can do this).

Network segmentation or VLANs could further protect against host discovery at the Ethernet layer.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_VLAN
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_segmentation

Comment: In Network segmentation, even if I create a segment for guests, all guests can see each other, right? I'm trying to avoid this...

Comment: There are a few options for isolating guests and preventing them from discovering each other, but you may want to look into Private VLANs: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_VLAN